# Adding Foreign Key ID attribute (reference) in my existing table/class

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am working with Entity Framework CodeFirst. I already created my objects with reference between them, executed update-databases with foreign keys, creating the database, example:

```
public class Order
{
   public virtual Bill Bill { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework created the table Order with the column: **Bill_Id**.
Now I have to keep my tables, rows and create a attribute referecing to this column that was created by Entity Framework.

I tried:

```
public class Order
{
   [ForeignKey("Bill_Id")]
   public virtual Bill Bill { get; set; }

   public Nullable<int> Bill_Id { get; set; } //The column is nullable
}
```

The project is running, but when I try to update a row using the Bill_Id, like:

```
Order o = _GetOrder();
o.Bill_Id = 2; //Reference
unitOfWork.Orders.Update(o);
```

It gives me this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.GetOtherEndOfRelationship(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity)
```

If I modify class to:

```
public class Order
{
   public virtual Bill Bill { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("Bill")]
   public Nullable<int> Bill_Id { get; set; } //The column is nullable
}
```

It gives me other error, that is not possible to rename my column.

How can I create an attribute to reference the column Foreign Key_Id that was automatically created by Entity Framework, keeping the rows?

*The reason I'm trying to do that is that I don't want to execute select to get the foreign key objects anymore. I just want to add a reference to them!*

Comment: I don't see `Bill_Id` column in your migration. Something is wrong with your explanation / [mcve].

Comment: Hey @IvanStoev I pasted the wrong migration

Comment: Ok. But I've tried to reproduce the issue by following the explained steps, and either `ForeignKey` approaches creates an empty migration. Latest EF6.1.3 if that matters.

Comment: Ok, but there is a possibility to create a migration that add the reference? I just want to EntityFramework knows that attribute it's the column that he created...

Comment: The foreign key reference should have been already created correctly by the first migration (when the `Order` had only `Bill` property).

Comment: @IvanStoev oh god...Really? I can create a script that create the column, execute an update and drop the old one...But do you think that it worth it? Because I am doing that just to not execute this Gets before inserts/updats.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. The column and the FK are already there. No migration is needed if that's the only change you've made. Again, I've tried to reproduce the issue in two step process - initial `Order` class (exactly how you posted it, just added `Id` property), update database, modified `Order` class by adding `Bill_Id` property and putting `ForeignKey` on `Bill` or `Bill_Id` - both work w/o database modification. In other words, your [mcve] is not verifiable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126158/discussion-between-lucks-and-ivan-stoev).